# how to extends only specific rules in parent class to child class, rather than all of them in sass?

Tags: css, sass

I have a parent class called .parent-form and I want to extend some of its rules in the child class, not all of them. Is that possible in SASS?

```
.parent-form {
    padding: 20px 10px;

    .form-control:focus {
        border-color: #2BBBAD;
    }

    .row {
        /*some css rules goes here*/
    }
}

.child-form {
   @extend .parent-form;
  /* I only need padding and .form-control, but not .row */
}
```

Is there any way to do that kind of thing in sass?

Comment: you can use the same class if you want to inherit the same traits, if you need to override the .row style for `.child-form` then just do that? Or just separate the common items into a common class

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I don't need to appear .row class inside the .child-form class. Is it possible?

Comment: You could use a mixin that just imports the properties you want

Comment: Is it not possible to somehow avoid getting inherited only the part of the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot selectively extend rules in a class while not taking the others. However you could do something like this:

```
.parent-form {
  padding: 20px 10px;
  .form-control:focus {
    border-color: #2BBBAD;
  }
}

.child-form {
  @extend .parent-form;
}

.needs-row {
  @extend .parent-form;
  .row {

  }
}

.child-form-with-row {
  @extend .needs-row;
}
```

Alternatively, you could do this with a mixin:

```
@mixin need-row($needRow) {
  @extend .parent-form;
  @if $needRow == true {
    .row {

    }
  }
}

.child-form-with-row {
  @include need-row(true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That's helpfull.

Comment: No problem. If the solution works for you, would you mind accepting the answer so other people who come across this question know it works/worked? (Also I get some rep!).

Comment: Sure. I'm new to StackOverflow. How can I do that? Hope you do the same thing to me!

Comment: At the top-left of my answer, under the up/down voting arrows, there should be an outline of a question mark, click that and it should go green. Thanks! P.S useful overview - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work